# Where is awklib?

Tags: debian, awk, gawk, documentation

I am working my way through *GAWK: Effective AWK Programming:
A User’s Guide for GNU Awk,* Edition 5.0; March, 2019.

I installed `gawk` using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gawk
```

On page 44 of the book there is the following:

The sample files are included in the gawk distribution, in the directory `awklib/eg/data`.

I cannot find `awklib/eg/data`, or any subset of this path. Where the heck is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Debian-based distributions (which I assume you’re using, given `apt-get`), the sample files are available in `/usr/share/doc/gawk/examples` (without `awklib` in the path).